# How to excute Fortran program in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a Fortran program and want to execute it in python for multiple files. I have 2000 input files but in my Fortran code I am able to run only one file at a time. How should I call the Fortran program in python?

**My Script:**

```
from numpy import f2py
with open("phase1.f") as sourcefile:
    sourcecode = sourcefile.read()
f2py.compile(sourcecode, modulename='add')
```

**Error:**

> Could not locate executable C:\Users\Vishnu\Anaconda2\python.exe
>   Executable C:\Users\Anaconda2\python.exe does not exist

Comment: It seems that you have a badly installed Python...

Answer (score 1):

For some starting places, take a look at https://cvw.cac.cornell.edu/python/combine. And consider F2Py, which is now included with numpy, I believe.

Regarding file paths, you may run into python interpreting C:\ as escaped, which I think is happening in your output above:

C:UsersVishnuAnaconda2python.exe

Try using:

```
'C:\\Users\\Vishnu\\Anaconda2\\python.exe'
```

or

```
r'C:\Users\Vishnu\Anaconda2\python.exe'
```

for example. See if that fixes the missing file problem.

[UPDATE]
I suspect the problem is somewhere in your user environment variables. Check the paths set there.

```
C:UsersVishnuAnaconda2python.exe
```

is trying to run your python, which is probably installed in:

```
C:\Users\Vishnu\Anaconda2\python.exe
```

Try simply typing 'environment' in your Start menu in windows. Check the paths there. That's a good place to start looking. (This may depend on which Windows you are using.)